# Super Resolution using OpenCV and Python appears to have no effect

Tags: python, opencv, deep-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I am trying to follow the code shown in this [link](https://learnopencv.com/super-resolution-in-opencv/) to apply Super Rez using OpenCV `cv2.dnn_superres.DnnSuperResImpl_create()` function.

I have downloaded the super res models from each repo ([LapSRN](https://github.com/fannymonori/TF-LAPSRN), [FSRCNN](https://github.com/Saafke/FSRCNN_Tensorflow/tree/master/models), and [ESPCN](https://github.com/fannymonori/TF-ESPCN/tree/master/export) )

I was expecting to have the same  results from the source blog

[image]

Instead, what I got was basically the image resized with tiny detail changes

[image]

Below is the code I used

```
sr = cv2.dnn_superres.DnnSuperResImpl_create()
 
path = "models/ESPCN_x3.pb"
 
sr.readModel(path)
 
sr.setModel("espcn",3)
 
result = sr.upsample(img)
cv2.imwrite('results/ss_ESPCN_x3.jpg', result)
 
# Resized image
resized = cv2.resize(img,dsize=None,fx=3,fy=3)
cv2.imwrite('results/ss_fx3.jpg', resized)
 
plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
plt.subplot(1,3,1)
# Original image
plt.imshow(img[:,:,::-1])
plt.subplot(1,3,2)
# SR upscaled
plt.imshow(result[:,:,::-1])
plt.subplot(1,3,3)
# OpenCV upscaled
plt.imshow(resized[:,:,::-1])
plt.show()
```

I also made sure to install the latest OpenCV contrib package

[image]

Is there something that I am missing?

Comment: I have the same issue in C++ with the latest cv version, any resolve?

Comment: unfortunately no, not yet.